# Mongo autocomplete in Zend Studio

Tags: autocomplete, mongodb, zend-studio

Does anyone know how to get auto complete for MongoDB to work in Zend Studio 8.  What would actually be an ideal solution is how to add autocomplete for any binary library not in the form of php files.

I.E. I know how to add a folder of php classes to the include path to get autocompletion, but mongo is a php plugin and not a collection of class files.  Possible there is a way to generate php files for Zend to use.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

At first you go [here](http://php100.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/adding-new-exts-to-zend-studio/) to see that there's a guy who has written a "reflector" of php classes which dumps the contents of a class to a file with phpdoc comments. Also there's [a link](https://github.com/smalyshev/Reflector) to sources where mongo.php is present as an example.

You can put that mongo.php into a folder and then in Zend Studio right-click a project, select "properties", go into "php include path -> libraries", click "add external source folder" and point to the folder with the mongo.php.

[image: Project settings in Zend Studio]

Voila, zend studio has autocompleting enabled now for MongoDB classes!

Don't know whether that mongo.php is up to date, but I'm using it without a problem.

I've put its code [here](http://pastebin.com/jmm6DLgH) just for a case.

---

*Probably a bit late answer, but it would be better than nothing ;)*